# Type Constraint Mismatch with default int * int type division

Tags: .net, f#

So I'm working through some sample F# code, and ran into the following fragment:

```
let divRem a b = 
    let x = a / b
    let y = a % b
    (x,y)
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

> HelloWorld\Program.fs(15,14): error FS0071: Type constraint mismatch
>   when applying the default type 'int * int' for a type inference
>   variable. The type '(int * int)' does not support any operators named
>   '/' Consider adding further type constraints

However, doing something like

```
let print n = System.Console.WriteLine(n.ToString())
print (4/2)
```

Results in

> 2

Why is the integer division operation not usable from within a function definition ?

**EDIT:**
Here is an entire sample of the code that fails to compile.

```
let divRem a b = 
    let x = a / b
    let y = a % b
    (x,y)

let print n = System.Console.WriteLine(n.ToString())
print (divRem (5,3))
```

Comment: Guessing by line numbers the actual error is when this function is used.  please post your entire F# file which fails to compile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you don't use comma's when calling functions in F#, commas are used to create tuples. The code should be:

```
let divRem a b = 
    let x = a / b
    let y = a % b
    (x,y)

let print n = System.Console.WriteLine(n.ToString())
print (divRem 5 3)
```

Comment: Actually these are round brackets, not commas, that designate the tuple here. The code compiles perfectly even if you use comma between `5` and `3`, but leads to rather unexpected result.

Comment: Commas create tuples, parentheses group things together to control the contents of the tuple. The code compiles if you place a comma between 3 and 5 because you create a tuple of ``(int -> int * int) * int``, which is perfectly valid but probably not what you want. You can see this as when run the code with a comma between 3 and 5 is run you see ``(Program+clo@7, 3)`` printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
let divRem (a, b) = 
    let x = a / b
    let y = a % b
    (x,y)

let print n = System.Console.WriteLine(n.ToString())
print (divRem (5,3))
```